# Losgelöste Appositionen – ein Anglizismus?

Tags: anglicism, apposition

In einer Buchrezension lese ich über die Hauptfigur:

> Die Tochter gestorben, die Ehe gescheitert, meldet er sich für die
>   UNO-Mission.

Man versteht zwar den Sinn des Satzes, aber kommt es nur mir so vor, als stimme hier einiges nicht? Formal hätten wir es mit Appositionen zu tun, die sich aber nicht grammatisch, sondern nur – und nur, wenn die Leser guten Willens sind – inhaltlich auf das Subjekt beziehen. Und der Bezugspunkt beider Appositionen muss das Subjekt sein, weil es das einzige in Frage kommende Wort im Nominativ ist (Die Tochter – die Ehe – er). *Er* kann aber weder in irgendeiner Form seine Tochter repräsentieren noch seine Ehe. *Er* kann es nur in seiner eigenen Rolle tun:

> Nach dem Verlust seiner Tochter gebrochen, mit seiner Ehe gescheitert, meldet er sich für die
>   UNO-Mission.

Damit fällt mir allerdings schon ein Grund ein für diese syntaktische Abkürzung »gegen die Einbahn«. Ich habe jetzt zwar korrekte Appositionen hergestellt, aber die beiden Ereignisse in einer Weise auf die Hauptfigur projiziert, wie ich das eigentlich nicht aus dem ursprünglichen Satz herauslesen durfte. Ich habe etwas dazuerfunden. Hingegen wird in der ursprünglichen Formulierung durch die enge Verbindung der zwei Halbsätze, die im Prinzip adverbiale Funktion haben, mit der Handlung des Hauptsatzes eine Kausalität zwar suggeriert, aber nicht ausgesprochen – in diesem Sinn die elegantere Lösung. Doch woher kommt diese Art der Formulierung? Ich glaube, aus dem Englischen:

> With his daughter dead and his marriage ruined, and nothing left to
>   keep him at home, he signed on for the UN mission.

Habe ich recht, dass wir es hier mit einem Anglizismus zu tun haben, oder leitet sich diese Art der Konstruktion mit »losgelösten Appositionen« von einer anderen sprachlichen Quelle ab?

Comment: Bin gespannt auf die Antworten - und hoffe, daß mich mein Bauchgefühl nicht trügt und irgendjemand eine Stelle aus einem Roman des 19. Jh. als Gegenbeweis beibringen kann.

Comment: Erinnert stark an das PPP aus dem Lateinischen. Ein Latinismus?

Comment: Ich finde den Satz völlig normal. Ich wäre nie auf die Idee gekommen, dass Partizpialsätze sich zwingend auf das gleiche Subjekt wie der eigentliche Satz beziehen müssen. Ich kann allerdings keine Textstellen als Beleg anführen, und wüsste auch gar nicht, wie ich danach suchen soll. Auch in z.B. Latein oder Japanisch ist diese Konstruktion völlig normal, es ist also definitiv kein Anglizismus.

Comment: ALs mich stört sdie Konstruktion zwar allgemeinnicht, aber in diesem Beispiel klingt sie mir dennoch komisch. Liegt wohl an der Intransitivitär von *sterben* und *scheitern*? Dem Beispiel von Emanuel liegt ja *[Er hatte] das Schwert geschultert* zugrunde, aber hier hatte er weder die Tochter gestorben noch die Ehe gescheitert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich meine, hier haben wir es letztlich mit einer Konstruktion zu tun, die in meiner Lateingrammatik als ablativus absolutus bezeichnet wird. Es handelt sich dabei um einen Nebensatz, der verkürzt wird mit Hilfe einer Partizipkonstruktion. Der Ablativ absolutus besteht aus einem Substantiv im Ablativ und einen Partizip im Ablativ. Es kann ein Partizip Präsens oder Perfekt Passiv sein. Bei Schriftstellern war diese Nebensatzverkürzung sehr beliebt.

Wir finden eine parallele Konstruktion im Englischen, zum Beispiel in Animal Farm

- With the worthless parasitical human beings gone, there was more for everyone to eat.

Eigentlich nicht verwunderlich, dass die lateinische Konstruktion Eingang in andere Sprachen gefunden hat. Im Deutschen wurde sie allerdings nie so recht heimisch und der obige Beispielsatz mit "Die Tochter gestorben …" ist nicht nur unschön, sondern schaut recht zusammengeflickt aus.
Im Deutschen würde man hier eher bevorzugen:

- Nach dem Tod seiner Tochter und dem Scheitern seiner Ehe meldet er sich für die Uno-Mission.

Man könnte im ursprünglichen Satz englischen Einfluss vermuten. Als Apposition würde ich eine solche Konstruktion aber nicht bezeichnen. Eine Apposition ist nachgestellt. Letztlich liegt doch immer die lateinische Absolutus-Konstruktion zu Grunde.

Übrigens ist die englische Partizip-Konstruktion mit eigenem Subjekt auch ohne with möglich. In meiner Raith-Grammatik finde ich in Paragraph 316 folgendes Beispiel:

Her father being ill, she could not leave the house.
Hier hat die Partizip-Konstruktion kausalen Sinn.

Edit:
Ich habe diese englische Konstruktion einfach with-construction getauft. Wenn man sich eingehender damit beschäftigt, stellt man fest, dass es hier Varianten gibt, die ineinander übergehen. Wenn das Partizip "being" ist fällt es meistens aus.

- With her father (being) ill, she could not leave the house.

Comment: Die Konstruktion erinnert definitiv an einen Ablativus absolutus. Doch vor ein paar Jahrzehnten, als vielleicht noch mehr Leute als heute lateinische Texte im Original gelesen haben, und sei es nur in der Schule (nur eine Vermutung), fand man solche Formulierungen in deutschen Printmedien noch äußerst selten, während sie heute fast schon häufig sind. Ein anderes Beispiel: "Den Tod des Vaters noch nicht verwunden, ließ sich die Enddreißigerin … von Michael Newtons Buch „Die Reisen der Seele“ inspirieren." Das ist wohl trotzdem nicht der dominierende Einfluss der Lektüre lateinischer Texte.

Answer (score 4):

Ich glaube, es handelt sich um eine Extrapolation einer ähnlichen, durchaus in der Literatur gängigen Formulierung:

> Das Schwert geschultert machte er sich auf den Weg.

[**Hier einige Belege**](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22verbannt%20begab%20er%20sich%22&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=de&oq=%22verbannt%20begab%20er%20sich%22&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...2895.3243.0.3568.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..3.0.0._T368CmtQ-o) von vor fast 200 Jahren für derartige Wendungen.

Im Kern haben wir eine adjektivische Phrase am Anfang, die uns Informationen über das Subjekt gibt. Das ist im Beispiel in der Frage auch der Fall. Nur dass dem Leser dort etwas mehr abverlangt wird.
Darin gleich einen Anglizismus zu vermuten halte ich für sehr abwegig. Sowas kann Deutsch schon auch ganz gut allein. Zudem ist die Struktur in Englisch ziemlich anders, denn wir haben "with" sowie, und das ist noch wichtiger, zwei Possessivpronomen. Wäre die deutsche Version ein Anglizismus, sollte sie in etwa so aussehen.

> Mit seiner Tochter tot und seiner Ehe gescheitert...

Tut sie aber nicht.

Comment: Vielleicht habe ich andere Beispiele aus diesem Link übersehen, aber die meisten folgen doch dem korrekten Schema Partizip Perfekt — Subjekt, z.B. "Aus seinem Vaterlande verbannt, begab er sich nach Trachin". Das ist in meinem Beispiel ja nicht der Fall. Auch bei "das Schwert geschultert" bezieht sich "geschultert" noch auf das Subjekt. Grammatisch richtig wäre hier "das Schwert schulternd".

Comment: Beziehungsweise müsste man hier noch weiter ausholen: "das Schwert geschultert" leitet sich zwar primär von der Passivkonstruktion "das Schwert wurde (sinngemäß: von ihm) geschultert" ab, sodass das Schwert im Nominativ steht, aber wenn man sich das Perfekt-Hilfszeitwort "haben" als Partizip Präsens  dazudenkt, ("das Schwert geschultert habend"), kann man es sich auch auf das Subjekt des Satzes bezogen denken. Das geht im Englischen mit "having" und "being", aber im Deutschen nicht.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... ja, es ist nicht genau dasselbe. Deshalb habe ich ja auch Extrapolation gesagt. Das Beispiel in deiner Frage ist eine logische Weiterführung. Dass "Das Schwert geschultert" von Passiv abstammt halte ich für unwahrscheinlich.Es ist ein einfaches Adjektiv. "Die Haare nass ging sie auf die Strasse.". Das ist genau die gleiche Konstruktion und hier steckt kein Passiv drin.

Comment: @Emanuel Nur würde man eher wieder "Mit nassen Haaren ging sie..." sagen

Comment: @Em1... was man eher sagen würde ist aber unerheblich. Wenn Schriftsteller immer nur das sagten, was man eher sagen würde, wäre die Literatur recht öde ;). Wenn du willst kann ich (un)gerne Beispiele raussuchen.

Comment: @Emanuel — Schultern, schulterte, geschultert. Das Schwert wird geschultert. Was ist daran unwahrscheinlich?

Comment: @MartinSchwehla.. hab' ich doch gesagt. Aber gerne nochmal ausführlicher... das Partizip 2 war ursprünglich einfach ein Adjektiv das das Resultat eines Verbs beschrieb. Daraus haben sich nach und nach Passiv und Perfekt entwickelt, aber der Adjektivcharakter scheint überall durch. Vor allem im Zustandspassiv. "Das Schwert geschultert" ist zunächst mal eine Information darüber, wie das Schwert ist. Das es durch jemanden in diesen Zustand gebracht wurde kann ja sein, aber es ist nicht der Fokus. Als Argument dafür vergleiche bitte den Satz mit den nassen Haaren.

Comment: ctd... wenn "geschultert" wirklich von "ist geschultert worden" abgeleitet sein sollte, dann hieße das, dass "Das Schwert geschultert" und "Die Haare nass" völlig unterschiedliche Herkünfte haben. Und genau das halte ich angesichts der oben erwähnten adjektivischen Herkunft des Partizip 2 für unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: Da liegt wohl ein grundsätzliches grammatisches Missverständnis vor. Dass Partizipien adjektivisch gebraucht werden können, heißt noch lange nicht, dass ihre Herkunft adjektivisch ist. Umgekehrt wird ein Schuh draus.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... dann forsch am besten einfach nochmal ein bisschen nach. Ich habe mir das nicht ausgedacht.

Comment: @Emanuel Done. Ich teile das Ergebnis auch gern mit dir: "Das Partizip II ist eine infinite Verbform mit der Argumentstruktur des zugrunde liegenden Verbs." Es lässt sich in der Funktion eines Adjektivs einsetzen. Komplette, sehr interessante Lektüre (und natürlich nur eine von vielen möglichen Quellen): http://www.zas.gwz-berlin.de/fileadmin/material/ZASPiL_Volltexte/zp14/zaspil16-zimmermann.pdf

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... wenn ich das richtig verstehe, dann geht es in der Arbeit darum, wie es HEUTE ist. Zumindest in deinem Zitat ist es so. Mir geht es aber darum, was es mal war und vor allem, wie es zum Partizip geworden ist. Schau dir dazu doch bei Belle Lettres mal die Folge zu "ge" an. Da wird das besser erklärt, als ich es gesagt habe. Oder wens schnell gehen soll: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96643/the-original-usage-of-past-participles  da sind Links zu weiteren Quellen.

Comment: Daniel Scholten schreibt zwar "Partizipien sind Adjektive und keine Verbalformen, ... das ist sowohl syntaktisch als auch sprachgeschichtlich falsch". Im Haupttext stellt er auch dar, was er damit meint: "Ich habe einen Baum gepflanzt" entsteht aus "Ich habe einen gepflanzten Baum". Ganz ähnlich das altenglische Beispiel, "Sie hatten den erschlagenen König". Daraus abzuleiten, dass sich "gepflanzt" nicht etwa aus der Verbform "pflanzen" ableitet, sondern immer schon eine eigene Adjektivform war, die vielleicht nur zufällig so klingt wie das Verb, ist ein großes Missverständnis.

Comment: (Teil 2) Es geht immer um den adjektivischen Gebrauch des Partizips, d.h., dass, um eine Handlung in der Vergangenheit auszudrücken, die Wirkung dieser Handlung auf das Objekt als neue Eigenschaft dieses Objekts angezeigt wird. Das ist etwas anderes. Aber legen wir diese Erkenntnis einmal auf das ursprüngliche Beispiel um, diesmal mit "echten" Adjektiven: "Die Schuhe braun, das Hemd grün, meldet er sich für die UNO-Mission". Klingt das jetzt besser? Für mich nicht, es sei denn, Giovanni Trapattoni wäre unlängst Mitglied des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung geworden.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... Zitat: "Daraus abzuleiten, dass sich "gepflanzt" nicht etwa aus der Verbform "pflanzen" ableitet, sondern immer schon eine eigene Adjektivform war"... so habe ich das auch nicht gemeint. Was ich meinte war, dass das Partizip 2 als Adjektiv benutzt wurde BEVOR es für Passiv oder Perfekt herangezogen wurde. Was das modifizierte Beispiel angeht... ich bin verwirrt. Was willst du mir damit zeigen? Ich hatte doch genau so ein Beispiel schon gegeben "Die Haare nass ging sie auf die Strasse". Das ist völlig in Ordnung, wenn auch natürlich keine Otto-Normal-Formulierung

Comment: Es wurde als Adjektiv verwendet, um eine Handlung in der Vergangenheit anzuzeigen = Vergangenheitsform = Perfekt (d.h. vollendet). Und ja, deshalb mein zarter Wink mit dem Zaunpfahl: "Haare nass und Flasche leer ging sie auf die Straße" — Trapattoni wäre damit sicher einverstanden ;-)

Comment: @MartinSchwehla... erstens: deine These, der ich mit meiner Adjektivtheorie widersprochen habe, war, dass es sich bei der Formulierung um ein verkürztes Passiv handelt. Die hast du bisher nicht verteidigt gekriegt. Was das andere angeht... ich entnehme den Trappatoni-Kommentar, dass du "Die Haare nass ging sie..." für falsches/windschiefes Deutsch hälts. Da bin ich fundamental anderer Ansicht. Ich werd dazu hier mal 'ne Frage machen.

Comment: Da hast du meine These missverstanden, ganz im Gegenteil. Passiv geht nur bei transitiven Verben, weder "sterben" noch "scheitern" ist eins davon. Das war eigentlich mein Punkt. Und zur neuen Frage: Auf die Antworten bin ich wirklich gespannt, ich werde mich aber nicht beteiligen ;-)