# Adjektivbasierte Phrase ohne Verb am Satzanfang: richtig, falsch, schlechter Stil?

Tags: style

In einer etwas [längeren Diskussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20631/losgel%C3%B6ste-appositionen-ein-anglizismus/20633?noredirect=1#comment46677_20633) bei einer anderen Frage ging es um Formulierungen folgender Art:

> Die Haare nass(,) ging sie auf die Straße.

Ich halte derartige Formulierungen für völlig ok, sowohl grammatisch also auch stilistisch. Ein anderer User war allerdings anderer Meinung und verglich sie mit trappatonihaftem Fragmentdeutsch.

- Sind solche Formulierungen grammatisch zulässig (wenn nein, warum nicht)?
- Sind sie stilistisch abzulehnen (wenn ja, warum)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* kann man sich bei solchen Wortgruppen die Partizipien *habend, seiend* o. Ä. hinzudenken:

> Den Kopf im Nacken [habend][,] lachte sie hell auf.

Sie werden daher den Partizipialgruppen wie z. B.

> Aus vollem Halse lachend[,] kam sie auf mich zu.

gleichgestellt. Somit gelten für sie auch die gleichen Kommaregeln wie für Partizipialgruppen. Als Grundregel gilt gemäß § 78 (3) des Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung, dass man Partizipial- oder entsprechende Wortgruppen durch Kommas abtrennen kann, es aber nicht muss. Die entsprechende Regel im Duden ist [Regel 114](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K114).
(Bei der alten Rechtschreibung wurden gemäß der alten Dudenregel 106 solche den Partizipialgruppen gleichgestellte Wortgruppen grundsätzlich mit Komma abgetrennt.)

Da solche Wortgruppen ausdrücklich in den Rechtschreibregeln erwähnt werden, sind sie sicherlich nicht falsch und vermutlich auch nicht ungewöhnlich.

Answer (score 2):

In geschriebener Sprache kann man sowas schon finden, aber es ist gekünstelt und imitiert die lateinische ablativus absolutus Konstruktion, zumindest eine Variante davon. Im Deutschen ist diese Konstruktion nie heimisch geworden, Englisch verwendet sie in geschriebener Sprache.

Aber reden tut so kein Mensch.

Comment: "Im Deutschen ist die K. nie heimisch geworden." Was bringt dich zu dieser Aussage?

Comment: Der lateinische Ablativus absolutus ist z.B Sole oriente urbem reliquit. Mit aufgehender Sonne verließ er die Stadt. Würdest du sagen das ist typisches Deutsch? Oder:Die Sonne aufgehend, verließ er die Stadt.

Comment: Nein, würde ich nicht sagen. Ist aber auch nicht die gleiche Konstruktion.